# How to optimize word_count in python

Tags: python, optimization, word-count

I am given n words **(1≤n≤10^5)**. Some words may repeat. For each word, I have to output its number of occurences. But the output order should correspond with the order of the first appearance of the word.

I have a working program of the problem, but for large inputs I am getting timeout. Here is my solution for the problem:

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
ll=[]

for x in range(n):
    l.append(raw_input())
    if l[x] not in ll:
        ll.append(l[x])

result = [ l.count(ll[x]) for x in range(len(ll)) ]

for x in range(len(result)):
    print result[x],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an ordered counter by subclassing `OrderedDict` and `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

counts = OrderedCounter(['b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
for k, c in counts.items():
    print(k, c)
```

Which prints:

```
b 3
c 2
a 1
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) for the `collections` module for a more complete recipe which includes a `__repr__` for `OrderedCounter`.

Comment: I would have suggested it, but I never remember the proper inheritance order to get the desired behavior, so using `__missing__` (which adds almost no complexity) worked equally well.

Comment: I love the conciseness, but this won't work with Python 2 (which seems like the one OP is using)

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes It works fine in Python 2 -- the only difference is that `print(k, c)` prints a tuple (and counts.items() returns a list).

Comment: Sorry, tried to import `Counter` from Python 2.6. It is defined in 3.3+ (and 2.7), so you're right (bloody old Centos...)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I did not yet try other answers but I think theirs are also workable

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to count items in python is to use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

Assuming you have a list of items in the order that you expect, passing it to a `Counter` should suffice:

```
c = collections.Counter(['foo', 'bar', 'bar'])
print(c['bar'])  # Will print 2
```

If `words` is the list of words you retrieved from the user, you can iterate over it to print the values:

```
seen = set()
for elem in words:
    if elem not in seen:
        print(counter[elem])
        seen.add(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It can handle this for you, and it removes the linear membership test expense using a `list` is imposing:

```
import collections

n = int(input())
l = []
ll = collections.OrderedDict()

for x in range(n):
    v = raw_input()
    l.append(v)
    ll[v] = None  # If v already in OrderedDict, does nothing, otherwise, appends

ll = list(ll)  # Can convert back to list when you're done if you like
```

If you need the count, you can make a custom class based on OrderedDict that both handles counts and remains ordered.

```
class OrderedCounter(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0
```

Then change `ll` to an `OrderedCounter`, and `ll[v] = None` to `ll[v] += 1`. At the end, `ll` will have the ordered words with their counts; `l` isn't even needed:

```
for word, count in ll.items():
    print(word, count)
```

The final code would simplify to just (omitting imports and class definition):

```
n = int(input())
word_counts = OrderedCounter()

for x in range(n):
    word_counts[raw_input()] += 1

for cnt in word_counts.values():
    print cnt,
```

Much simpler, right?